# Install root certificate to Node.js (HTTPS Client)

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I would like to connect to an internal corporate server with Node.js as a client via HTTPS. 
How do I install my internal root certificate to Node.js, so the certificate validation is successful?

**I don't want to disable certificate validation.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Use this, it works as charm: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas

1. Create a certificates folder
2. Place your root certificate there
3. Load the certificate with the module metnioned above

If you use Sails.js, put the code to config/bootstrap.js

Comment: Link rot: the link redirections take you to a lost domain.

Answer (score 4):

Add an [environment variable](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file):

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=file
```

> When set, the well known "root" CAs (like VeriSign) will be extended with the extra certificates in file. The file should consist of one or more trusted certificates in PEM format. A message will be emitted (once) with process.emitWarning() if the file is missing or malformed, but any errors are otherwise ignored.
>
> Note that neither the well known nor extra certificates are used when the ca options property is explicitly specified for a TLS or HTTPS client or server.
>
> This environment variable is ignored when node runs as setuid root or has Linux file capabilities set.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help someone:

```
var https = require('https');

var fs = require('fs');

var https_options = {

  key: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/private.key"),

  cert: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/your_domain_name.crt"),

  ca: [

          fs.readFileSync('path/to/CA_root.crt'),

          fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca_bundle_certificate.crt')

       ]
};
```

Ref: https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/how-to-install-ssl-certificate-on-node-js/

And you can use this link to check your cert:
https://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: The missing vital line is the next one in the referenced link:

`https.createServer(https_options, ...`

Don't forget to pass the set of options to the createServer constructor/initializer.